# Xamarin PushViewController Zoom to subview

Tags: ios, ios7, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Using Xamarin.iOS to develop an iPhone app. 
I would like to achieve the same kind of animation as in the iPhone iOS7 Home Screen, where you zoom in to an app. I have a set of pictures in a Collection view. Each picture corresponds to a person, where you can tap the pic, to get to the next view controller, where you get information about the person .

Right now I am animating from bottom to top - would it be possible to achieve my desired animation type?

```
public override void ItemSelected (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                UIStoryboard MainStoryboard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("MainStoryboard_iPhone",null);
                PersonDetailViewController personDetailViewController = MainStoryboard.InstantiateViewController ("PersonDetailViewController") as PersonDetailViewController;
                personDetailViewController.personID =  _viewController.Category.Persons [indexPath.Row].Id;
                this._viewController.NavigationController.PushViewController (personDetailViewController,false);
                var animation = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("transform.translation.y");
                animation.Duration = 0.3f;
                animation.From = NSNumber.FromFloat(this._viewController.View.Frame.Height);
                animation.To = NSNumber.FromFloat(0f);
                this._viewController.NavigationController.View.Layer.AddAnimation(animation, "animate");
                this._viewController.NavigationController.View.Layer.AnimationForKey("animate");

            }
```

Comment: You can use custom view controller transitions on iOS7. Look here: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios_7/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this sample at objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html) of a zooming transition - hopefully you can translate from the Objective-C.  Here's the animation part:

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController* toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController* fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    [[transitionContext containerView] addSubview:toViewController.view];
    toViewController.view.alpha = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
        fromViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1);
        toViewController.view.alpha = 1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        fromViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];

    }];

}
```